# Android app with many diagrams - memory issue

Tags: android, image, memory

I have an Android app with several activities and within those activities are around 16 diagrams (JPEGs approx 1200px x 800px, around 300kb each). There are a maximum of 3 diagrams per activity.

I am using BitmapFactory to load the images and scale them accordingly and it's all working fine on devices of all sizes (including devices with small memory).

My question is, I am wanting to add more activities, and another 16 diagrams (again, no more than 3 per activity). Will this make a difference to the memory management for my app? I realise my overall app install size will be larger, but in terms of the amount of RAM the app uses, will it stay the same?

My thinking is that the RAM only loads the diagrams in the activity that is currently being viewed so really it's only 3 that are being loaded at once? So in theory would another 16 images make a difference to my app performance?

Thanks!

Comment: So for example, if I have an app with 10 activities and 3 images in each activity. This app uses around 20mb of RAM on average. If I want to add another 10 activities, with another 3 images per page to the app, would the app still use around 20mb of RAM because only one activity is still being viewed at a time? Obviously the size of the APK would double...but I want to make sure the RAM usage would not double from 20mb to 40mb in this example

Answer (score 0):

The amount of RAM usage will increase with the increase of number of processes and images in the activity. You can monitor use application and each activity using android monitor which may highlight the RAM usage for your application w.r.t activities.

Comment: Yes I have done this and it's all ok, but I am wondering if I add more activities and more diagrams, will the RAM usage increase? It shouldn't do because if the user is still only viewing one activity and 3 diagrams at a time, then it doesn't matter whether there are 3 or 300 built in really?

Comment: In this case I would ask you to use android monitor to see RAM usage. If it works for you accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I created a second version of my app with 50% less activities and diagrams and tested this and the average RAM was about the same so this pretty much answers my own question, that the RAM use would not increase by increasing the activities and number of images.